# Pandas percentage calculation using two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I'm trying to calculate the percentage of sales using the total sales for each multi-index.
My DataFrame is like this:

```
local   categoria   fabricante   tipo      consistencia    peso         pacote   ordem vendas_kg
AREA I  SABAO       ASATP        DILUIDO   LIQUIDO         1501 A 2000g PLASTICO 1    10
AREA I  SABAO       TEPOS        DILUIDO   LIQUIDO         1501 A 2000g PLASTICO 1    20
AREA I  SABAO       ASATP        CAPSULA   LIQUIDO         1501 A 2000g PLASTICO 1    20
AREA I  SABAO       TEPOS        CAPSULA   LIQUIDO         1501 A 2000g PLASTICO 1    30
AREA I  SABAO       ASATP        DILUIDO   LIQUIDO         1501 A 2000g PLASTICO 2    20
AREA I  SABAO       TEPOS        DILUIDO   LIQUIDO         1501 A 2000g PLASTICO 2    30
AREA I  SABAO       ASATP        CAPSULA   LIQUIDO         1501 A 2000g PLASTICO 2    20
AREA I  SABAO       TEPOS        CAPSULA   LIQUIDO         1501 A 2000g PLASTICO 2    30
AREA II SABAO       ASATP        DILUIDO   LIQUIDO         1501 A 2000g PLASTICO 1    10
AREA II SABAO       TEPOS        DILUIDO   LIQUIDO         1501 A 2000g PLASTICO 1    15
AREA II SABAO       ASATP        CAPSULA   LIQUIDO         1501 A 2000g PLASTICO 1    25
AREA II SABAO       TEPOS        CAPSULA   LIQUIDO         1501 A 2000g PLASTICO 1    35
AREA II SABAO       ASATP        DILUIDO   LIQUIDO         1501 A 2000g PLASTICO 2    20
AREA II SABAO       TEPOS        DILUIDO   LIQUIDO         1501 A 2000g PLASTICO 2    25
AREA II SABAO       TEPOS        CAPSULA   LIQUIDO         1501 A 2000g PLASTICO 2    20
AREA II SABAO       TEPOS        CAPSULA   LIQUIDO         1501 A 2000g PLASTICO 2    30
```

So I'm calculation the total sales for each unique tuple in index and storing as a total data frame. My goal is to calculate each ['fabricante'] market share, but for now I'm aiming on TEPOS.`
After pivoting my DataFrame become something like this:

```py
                                       sum           sum
                                 vendas_kg     vendas_kg
fabricante                           ASATP         TEPOS      Total
local          tipo      ordem 
AREA I         DILUIDO     1          10            20         30
                           2          20            30         50
               CAPSULA     1          10            20         30
                           2          20            30         50
AREA II        DILUIDO     1          10            15         25
                           2          20            25         45
               CAPSULA     1          25            35         55
                           2          20            30         50
```

The code I'm using to calculate total and to create the dataframe with multiindex is:

```py
#creating a sample from all data

a = df.sample(n=50)

#creating a multiindex dataframe

temp_df = pd.pivot_table(a.fillna(value=0), index=['tipo','local','pacote'],columns=['fabricante'], values=['vendas_kg'], fill_value=0, aggfunc=[np.sum])
total = temp_df.sum(level=1, axis=1)

#calculating the marketshare for Tepos

temp_df[('sum','vendas_kg','TEPOS')] = temp_df[('sum','vendas_kg','TEPOS')] / temp_df.sum(level=1, axis=1)
```

Two thing are happing, if I use all columns all data becomes NaN, if I use the above code.

```py
ValueError: cannot join with no level specified and no overlapping names
```

My goal is to have something like this:

```
                                       sum           sum
                                 vendas_kg     vendas_kg
fabricante                           ASATP         TEPOS     % segment  Total
local          tipo      ordem 
AREA I         DILUIDO     1          33%            66%         50%     30
                           2          40%            60%         50%     50
               CAPSULA     1          33%            66%         50%     30
                           2          40%            60%         50%     50
AREA II        DILUIDO     1          40%            60%        31.25%   25
                           2         44.44%         55.56%      47.37%   45
               CAPSULA     1         43.64%         57.36%      53.63%   55
                           2          40%            60%        53.63%   50
```

Can anybody help me ?
Find more info about the data and objectives on : [Percentage calculation in pivot table pandas with columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55288279/percentage-calculation-in-pivot-table-pandas-with-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
df_percent = temp_df.apply(lambda x: round(x / x.sum() * 100, 2), axis = 1)

                            sum
                            vendas_kg
              fabricante    ASATP   TEPOS
tipo    local   pacote      
CAPSULA AREA I  PLASTICO    40.00   60.00
        AREA II PLASTICO    22.73   77.27
DILUIDO AREA I  PLASTICO    37.50   62.50
        AREA II PLASTICO    42.86   57.14
```

To add `total` column, do:

```
df_percent['total'] = total
```

---

**Explanation**

The `apply` is equivalent a loop, and the **axis** command tells the apply he will roll in columns. What the code do is just take each row value and divide by the sum of entire row. The way I implemented only works before you add other columns like `total`

Comment: Great ! It work! Can you elaborate a little about what I was doing wrong and how this code work ? Because I need to go a little further on some calculations, if you can take a look at this other question you'll understand the role idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55288279/percentage-calculation-in-pivot-table-pandas-with-columns

Comment: @LeandroEleutério If my answer helped you, consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)